# Grails: save parsed csv data to database

Tags: csv, parsing, grails

I have successfully parsed by csv using grails plugin. Now the output looks like:

This is how i parsed the csvFile. I need to save this csv contents to database.How can i do this?

```
def upload = {
    def f = request.getFile('filecsv')
    if (f.empty) {
        flash.message = 'file cannot be empty'
        render(view: 'uploadForm')
        return
    } else {

        def file = request.getFile('filecsv')
        def singlerow = file.inputStream.toCsvReader(['charset': 'UTF-8', 'separatorChar': '|']).eachLine{
            line ->
                println "The data are"+line


        }
    }
}
```

#### Output looks like

```
The data are[test, 2017-08-21, , , 2017-08-21, 100, 8668a73e55e0824c130337d49f0fc746, , Annual, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , test, 1111, test, test, 1901-03-13, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , asd/asd/sad/incentive/20170906/09062017.csv, 2017-09-06, , 4.7, 30430001]
The data are[test, 2017-10-07, , , 2017-08-07, 100, asdasdasdasd, , An, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , test, 1111, test, test, 1900-02-15, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , stat/test/test/incentive/20170906/ 09072017.csv, 2017-09-06, , 4.7, 30430001]
```

My domain class:

```
class Data {

String data1
Date data12
Date data13
Date data14
Date data15
String data16
String data17
String data18
String data19
String data110
String data111
String data112
String data113
String data114
String data115
String data115
String data116
String data117
String data118
String data119
String data120
_____________
__________
___________
```

}
How can i save this to database of this domain class.

Comment: So, you have a class name all-lowercase and your properties are called data*? that's already horrible...

Comment: my bad. i just edited my class so that it does not become original :)

Comment: The strings should work fine the issue will be dates, remember you are parsing flat text so when you parse the date element it will be a string text of that value ... so you need to convert those to be real date - before storing them using `SimpleDateFormat`

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing other details, the easiest way to save such domain instances I can think of is:

```
static dates = [ 11, 12, 13, 14 ] // positions of fields to be converted to Date

def upload = {
  //...
  file.inputStream.toCsvReader(['charset': 'UTF-8', 'separatorChar': '|']).eachLine{ line ->
    def map = [:]
    line.eachWithWithIndex{ d, ix -> 
      // if( d ) map[ "data${ix+1}" ] = dates.contains( ix ) ? Date.parse( 'yyyy-MM-dd', d ) : d
      if( d ) map[ "data${ix+1}" ] = d // if you need no date conversion
    }
    Data data = new Data( map )
    if( !data.save() ) log.warn "save failed: $data.errors"
  }
}
```

Comment: So what if i do not need to convert to date.How can i save this?

Comment: I can not see the changes in database :)